# Is there a way to upgrade from 12.04 desktop to 14.04 beta directly?

Tags: upgrade

Is there a way to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 directly, maybe through terminal? If so, could you tell me? I don't want to wait till 14.04 comes out but I don't want to upgrade three times to get it.

I've had 13.10 on another machine. The speed difference is noticeable, even though this machine had Ubuntu preinstalled and is quite speedy with 12.04.

Thank you in advance.
Any answer is appreciated.